# Puppeteer how to specify a button if there are multiple buttons of that same class type?

Tags: javascript, html, puppeteer

I'm trying to use Puppeteer to click on a button.

The webpage in my script has a grid which acts as a calendar and each date is a button. The issue is that every date button is of the same class type and I so I couldn't single out a specific date.

I tried to identify the buttons by the aria label it still wouldn't work.

I then tried to click the "Go Forward 5 Days" button using the aria label and that didn't work either.

I have read that it might be available by iterating through the parent element in the HTML tree and then just picking the one that I want (example: putting the calendar element into a variable and then choosing the child I want[7]), but this really isn't ideal and I'm hoping there is another way.

```
const puppeteer = require ('puppeteer');

async function Main()
{
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({product: 'chrome', headless: false});
    const page1 = await browser.newPage();
    const url1 = 'https://www.recreation.gov/camping/campgrounds/232446/availability';
    await page1.goto(url1);
    return page1;
}

async function selectDates(page){
    const button = await page.$('aria/Go Forward 5 Days[role="button"]');
    await button.click();
}

async function startCheckout()
{
    const page = await Main();
    await selectDates(page);
}

startCheckout();
```

Here's the button in HTML if it helps any:

```
<button class="rec-availability-date" aria-label="Jun 10, 2021 - Not Available">X</button>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! I shortened your text -- after all that reading, I'm still not sure which button you want to click. Can you clarify what makes the button you've shown special? Is it the 7th button, the aria label, .... ? Thanks.

Comment: @ggorlen hello thanks for that. yea I guess my wall of text was a little long haha. Realistically the button I would like to click the most is any of the date buttons that are available. If you go on the webpage you'll see that most are reserved so they are not clickable, but the ones that are available are. I can go to like bestbuys website and click anything, but on this webpage I can't get it to work.

Comment: So you want to check all of the available "A" cells or just specific ones? Do you want to add to cart afterwards or...? The buttons that are available appear to be in `td.available` elements, so I'd try `button.click("td.available .rec-availability-date");` although I haven't tested it yet.

Comment: @ggorlen Just specific dates. Let's say for example the 26th of this month was available. I would like to specify in code that I want to click on the 26th for the A cells. I would then click automate "add to cart" only if the date was available and my script clicked it. Thank you I'll try what you suggested  at least to see if I can manage a click. If you have an idea how I could click on a specific date though I'd love to hear it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax for selecting DOM elements via their attributes is this:

```
// Click "5 days > "
await page.click('[aria-label="Go Forward 5 Days"]');

// Click a specific day:
await page.click('[aria-label="Jun 17, 2021 - Site 091 is available"]');

// Add to cart
await page.WaitForSelector('button.availability-page-book-now-button-tracker');
await page.click('button.availability-page-book-now-button-tracker');
```

Also see these articles on selecting elements via attributes:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors/Attribute_selectors

Comment: Hello thank you for your help. I did try your suggestion, but unfortunately it did not work. I get this error message: Error: No node found for selector: [aria-label="Go Forward 5 Days"]. It's confusing because that is the aria label on that button and my understanding is that a button is a node on the DOM tree. EDIT: I think it just worked once. But only once and after running the script again not changing anything it keeps failing. I know it worked too because there is no error thrown in the terminal. Is it possible that maybe it's trying to click the button before it gets loaded in?

Comment: Ok so looking at the Puppeteer docs it seems page.goto has a waituntil option. Well I added a wait until content loaded option: await page1.goto(url2,{ waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded' }); and it now works most of the time. I still get the same no node found error every once in a big while and I also noticed that if I scroll the page with the mouse's scroll wheel it will throw an error saying the node isn't visible or not an html element. All in all we're making progress haha. If you have any idea as to what is causing the rare error message now I would love to hear it because I am lost

Comment: Be sure to `waitForSelector` for nodes you want to interact with (if they are 100% going to be present)

Comment: Hello Vaviloff one final question, why did you use: await page.WaitForSelector('button.availability-page-book-now-button-tracker'); if that is only part of the class name. Will puppeter look for a string that matches what you entered and assign that to the WaitForSelector and click methods?

Comment: That selector, while partial, is enough to exactly match just one specific button we're after.